# hammer-time.min.js contains undefined function hasTouchNone

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I downloaded hammer-time.min.js and when I run, I am getting an exception on my browser.

> TypeError: this.hasTouchNone is not a function. (In 'this.hasTouchNone(a.target)', 'this.hasTouchNone' is undefined)

Am I missing a library?

**Update:**
I have tried downloading the full Javascript (non-minified version). And it is working fine. When I checked the code, the hasTouchNone function is not in the code.

Comment: you are right, i faced the same issue, minified and normal versions differs, thanks for your self-answer.

Comment: thanks. solved the problem

Comment: This should be reported to the project, https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer-time/issues

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you answered it yourself with:

> Update: I have tried downloading the full Javascript (non-minified version). And >it is working fine. When I checked the code, the hasTouchNone function is not in >the code.